# method SetActive (true); does not work С# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game where you need to control the ball, on collision the ball disappears using the method `player.SetActive (false);`
After that, a window with a notification about the loss should come out, I use the `SetActive (true);` method for all window elements, but it does not appear (all window elements are initially disabled)
I tried to leave all the windows on, and then turn them off through the script at the very beginning of the game, in order to turn them on at the end of the game. Items just disappear and don't show up anymore

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject restart;
    public GameObject label;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject particle;
    public GameObject particleDeath;
    public GameObject Box;
    public GameObject Menu;

    public static bool lose = false;

    void Awake(){
        lose = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other){
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "bomb")
            lose = true;
            restart.SetActive (true);          //does not work
            label.SetActive (true);            //does not work
            particleDeath.SetActive (true);    //does not work
            player.SetActive (false);
            particle.SetActive (false);
            Box.SetActive (true);              //does not work
            Menu.SetActive (true);             //does not work
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be various reasons for this, but you mention that you deactivate the gameobjects at the beginning of the game running, could it be that once they are activated, that the function that deactivates them runs immediately afterwards? Thus having the appearance of them not turning on?
Alternatively, do the objects have parents that are disabled? Then they will appears disabled still.

Comment: I don't have a function in my code that disables its desired window, I only need to enable it.
no parents

Comment: Are you disabling the player object with the script on as well? That might explain it then.
Without seeing the scene setup/other scripts it can be hard to debug, but if you SetActive(false) on the object with the script doing the disabling/activation, that object will no longer be able to do anything(no functions will be called).
Other than that, I would try and debug with either breakpoints or Debug.Log to see if the objects get enabled and then disabled immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured it out: if you call `setActive(false)` then the `update()` method of that object will not be called anymore. I tried setting `setActive(false)` in `start()` method and then `setActive(true)` in `update()` method after some condition. The update method never ran after setting `setActive(false)`. The sollution is to use meshrenderer which does similarly (deactivates the mesh thus hiding the object):

```
private MeshRenderer renderer1;

void Start()
    {
        renderer1 = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(); // Get the Mesh Renderer that is attached to this GameObject
        renderer1.enabled = false; // Disable the renderer so that it is invisisble
    }

    
    void Update()
    {

        if (DigScript.finishedDigging)
        {
            renderer1.enabled = true;
            Debug.Log("Ok now show bone  " + renderer1.enabled);

        }
        
    }
```

Hope this helps...